# assembly set label value to negative value

Tags: assembly, lc3

I am writing an encryption program for an LC3 project at school in assembly and can't seem to store certain values in labels. I don't want the solution to the program just how to store a negative value in a label.
Code I have tried:

```
EOL .FILL #-32
```

I just can't seem to figure out why the assembler thinks that this means `TRAP xE0`.

Comment: What assembler are you using? The answer that works for you will likely depend on the answer to that.

Comment: Since xE0 is -32, I'd have to guess (you don't provide all the code) you placed `EOL .FILL #-32` before code and the processor tried to execute the data (-32) as code. Place variables after your `HALT` and before `.end` or anywhere after the last instruction your program uses.

Comment: I am assuming this is LC3 as its the only environment where this would make sense.

Comment: You should make a [mcve] but I can only guess that your problem is with where you put your variables and that the duplicate question and answer should solve your issue.